# Bind the vue to root element after plugin finishes ajax call

Tags: javascript, plugins, vue.js

I am binding my application root element #app to vue and before that I am loading my custom plugin with Vue.use(myplugin). My plugin makes an ajax call, load the data and set it into Vue.$permission property.. so in short I want to load my user permission before mounting the app. but while my ajax call is fetching permission data, app is mounted and my page is getting rendered, which need the permission object.

is there a way I can bind the app root element to vue after my plugin finishes.. or any other alternate solution?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, that's quite simple actually:

```
const Vue = require('vue');

const vueInstance = new Vue({
    // don't specify the 'el' prop there
});

doingAnAjaxCall() // assuming it returns a promise
    .then(() => {
        vueInstance.$mount('#root'); // only now the vue instance is mounted
    });
```

> If a Vue instance didn’t receive the el option at instantiation, it will be in “unmounted” state, without an associated DOM element. vm.$mount() can be used to manually start the mounting of an unmounted Vue instance.

See: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-mount

So for your case you may use any asynchronous mechanism to detect the end of the ajax call. Maybe the simplest solution is to pass a callback function to your plugin object, and mount your vue instance inside.

```
 /* Define plugin */
 MyPlugin = {};
 MyPlugin.install = function(Vue, options) {
     doingAnAjaxCall()
         .then(data => {
             // do something with data
             options.callback();
         });
 };

 const Vue = require('vue');

 /* Create the vue instance */
 const vueInstance = new Vue({
     // don't specify the 'el' prop there
 });

 /* Install the plugin */
 Vue.use(MyPlugin, { // This object will be passed as options to the plugin install()
     callback: () => {
         vueInstance.$mount('#root'); // only now the vue instance is mounted
     }
 });
```